# Disable Text Selection in TextBox Style

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, textselection

I want to disable the selection of text in a textbox using a style preferably. The reason is that I have a style that makes a textbox look like a textblock until a certain criteria (IsRenaming) is met. These are the nodes of a treeview so I don't want the user to be able to select the text. Here is the style:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBlockStyleForTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="RenamingTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBlockStyleForTextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Arrow"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsRenaming}" Value="true">
                <DataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="TextBox.IsReadOnly" Value="False" />
                    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="IBeam" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" >
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource WhiteColor}"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2" />
                    <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="behaviors:TextBoxBehavior.SelectAll" Value="True"/>
                </DataTrigger.Setters>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

I don't think I am overriding the IsReadOnly anywhere. Here is my textbox definition:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate" >
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
                 Tag="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeView}}"
                 Style="{StaticResource RenamingTextBox}">
```

... etc

Comment: so what's not working? looks binding should trigger IsReadOnly just fine

Comment: What does your TextBox definition look like?  Are you overriding the IsReadOnly property (or any others from your style) there?

Comment: @WonkotheSane - I added my definition of the TextBox above. They are defined in HierarchicalDataTemplates and I don't see where I override that property anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quick and dirty, but it's a good start/example from our conversation in the other answer, you can and additional tweaks to the style, but it totally works (just  tested it)

```
<Style x:Key="RenamingTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="block" Visibility="Visible" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" Margin="1.5"/>
                            <TextBox x:Name="box" Visibility="Collapsed" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsRenaming}" Value="true">
                                <DataTrigger.Setters>
                                    <Setter TargetName="block" Property="TextBox.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="box" Property="TextBox.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                </DataTrigger.Setters>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, one quick way to disallow text from being highlighted is to add
to your styles toggle of IsEnabled. Otherwise, you might want to override a TextBox's Template, with a StackPanel, that toggles the TextBox and a TexBlock - super easy to do, and ton of samples all over, even here on stack overlow.
Here's a your modified style with IsEnabled..

```
<Style x:Key="TextBlockStyleForTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="RenamingTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBlockStyleForTextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Arrow"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsRenaming}" Value="true">
                <DataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="TextBox.IsReadOnly" Value="False" />
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="IBeam" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" >
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource WhiteColor}"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2" />
                </DataTrigger.Setters>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Only problem with setting IsEnabled is it then greys out the text and background making it LOOK disabled. I want it to look enabled...just not be selectable/highlightable :)

Comment: Example of toggling between textblock and textbox? Or can you add the link to an example for future reference so others don't need to search?

Comment: sure, give me a bit, I'll either find it, or quickly type that up for you

Comment: @KrisTrip, ok, just typed something up... seems faster than looking up , but I swear there's tone of stuff out there, I just don't have my google foo on today

Answer (score 0):

Your styles are working just fine, as I just tested them! 
3 possible problems:

1. You are not binding the TextBox correctly
2. Your are not assigning your style
3. IsRemaining isn't raising property changed

   ---

   ### here's my test

   ```
   <Window x:Class="Sample.MainWindow"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   Height="500" Width="600" 
   x:Name="wnd">
      <Window.Resources>
          ...I put your styles in there..
      </Windows.Resources>
   <StackPanel>
       <TextBox DataContext="{Binding ViewModel, ElementName=wnd}" Style="{StaticResource RenamingTextBox}" >tata</TextBox>
       <Button Command="{Binding ViewModel.SomeCommand, ElementName=wnd}">change read only</Button>
   </StackPanel>
   ```

code behind (.xaml.cs)

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        ViewModel = new ViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();          
    }
    }

public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DelegateCommand _someCmd;
    private bool _isRenaming;

    public DelegateCommand SomeCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _someCmd ?? (_someCmd = new DelegateCommand(() =>
                                                                {
                                                                    IsRenaming = true;
                                                                }));
        }
    }

    public bool IsRenaming
    {
        get { return _isRenaming; }
        set
        {
            _isRenaming = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsRenaming");
        }
    }
      }
```

Comment: The other parts of the style work great. When IsRenaming is true it makes it look like a textbox and allows editing. Normally it doesn't allow editing but still allows selection. I don't want users to be able to select the text (makes it hard to read).

Comment: well, i think you might want to look into toggling textBlock (for read only behavior) vs TextBox for editing.

Comment: you could set the system key color SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey (but then the rest of your app will default to that too):

<Style.Resources>
   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="LightGreen"/>
</Style.Resources>